# why can't I add a new List object in button event

Tags: c#, list, events

why can't I add a new item/object to my list in button (or combobox etc.) events? I mean, the events don't see my list if it's outside of the brackets...it's underlined in red... can you help me?

long story short: i want to add a new object by clicking the button

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;

namespace Samochody
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


        List<Samochod> ListaSamochodow = new List<Samochod>();
            comboBox1.DataSource = ListaSamochodow;
            comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Marka";
            XmlRootAttribute oRootAttr = new XmlRootAttribute();
            XmlSerializer oSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Samochod>), oRootAttr);
            StreamWriter oStreamWriter = null;
            oStreamWriter = new StreamWriter("samochody.xml");
            oSerializer.Serialize(oStreamWriter, ListaSamochodow);
        }


        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {



            try
            {
                ListaSamochodow.Add(new Samochod(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text, Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text)));

            }
            catch (Exception oException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Aplikacja wygenerowała następujący wyjątek: " + oException.Message);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should instantiate your list globally and not under Form1_Load event.
that way it will be accessible all around your class (the window in this case).

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work fine. You might need to set your textboxes to contain valid values when you start the form. also make sure that you make the list visible throughout your form1 class.

```
namespace Samochody
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        // make sure your list looks like this, created outside your functions.
        List<Samochod> ListaSamochodow = new List<Samochod>();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            label1.Text = "the amount in your list is " + ListaSamochodow.Count.ToString();
            textBox1.Text = "string here";
            textBox2.Text = "string here";
            textBox3.Text = "100";
        }


        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            XmlRootAttribute oRootAttr = new XmlRootAttribute();
            XmlSerializer oSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Samochod>), oRootAttr);
            StreamWriter oStreamWriter = null;
            oStreamWriter = new StreamWriter("samochody.xml");
            oSerializer.Serialize(oStreamWriter, ListaSamochodow);
        }


        private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Samochod s = new Samochod(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text, Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text));
            ListaSamochodow.Add(s);
            label1.Text = "the amount in your list is " + ListaSamochodow.Count.ToString();

        }
    }
}
```